# Is there a "Moore's law" for humanity's ability to accurately measure fundamental physical constants?

Tags: measurements, physical-constants

The [CODATA releases](https://pml.nist.gov/cuu/Constants/Table/allascii.txt) seem to represent the scientific consensus on what their values approximately are. Their accuracy improves over time.

Say, for the electron mass, would it be accurate to expect a constant improvement of maybe one more digit every two years? Or did measurement accuracy for some constants speed up over time?

Looking at the historical data, electron mass measurement accuracy seems to have improved by around 3 decimal digits in about 32 years, so J.G.'s estimation below seems closer to the truth in this case.

```
1986 9.109 389 7(54) e-31 kg
1998 9.109 381 88(72) e-31 kg
2002 9.109 382 6(16) e-31 kg
2006 9.109 382 15(45) e-31 kg
2010 9.109 382 91(40) e-31 kg
2014 9.109 383 56(11) e-31 kg
2018 9.109 383 7015(28) e-31 kg
```

Comment: I'm following this question because I'd love to see someone empirically document how precision has improved over time. All I can contribute is this: $N$ measurements of error $\sigma$ can get us a $\sigma/\sqrt{N}$ error but, even at fixed $\sigma$, $N$ may exponentially grow due to Moore's law _for some_ ways of gathering data... funding pending. On the most naïve model, this would get us one extra decimal point by multiplying $N$ by $100$, in $13.3$ years if it doubles in two.

Comment: +1 for your edit. If we interpret that example as a rough way to estimate Moore's law's doubling time, it becomes $19.3$ months (well, $17.6$ if I bare in mind the errors' significant figures).

Comment: @J.G. I started writing a small visualization: https://github.com/void4/parseCODATA

Comment: That's a good idea. But if you use an inverted logarithmic $y$-axis for the error, so you're more precise than counting an integer-valued number of correct decimal places, any linear trend (or deviations from same) will be even clearer. It will be _even_ clearer if you look at an average of these polygonal paths, rather than just them individually.

Comment: It just divides first uncertainty value by the later uncertainty values and takes the log of that, I now commented it a bit more. Agreed re. the bundles

Comment: Rather than “number of digits,” prefer the “fractional uncertainty,” which is the uncertainty (whose first digits are shown in the parentheses) divided by the magnitude of the value. So your 1986 value has fractional uncertainty $\frac{54}{9.1}\times10^{-8} \approx 60\rm\,ppb$, while the 2018 value has $\frac{28}{9.1}\times10^{-10} \approx 0.3\rm\,ppb$, with “parts per billion” equal to a factor $10^{-9}$.

Comment: @rob That first one is more like 60 ppb.

Comment: @J.G. Oops. A perfect opportunity to abuse my moderator superpowers.